# Bootstrap modal won't appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm just trying to get the tutorial sample modal to show. I have the exact code from the tutorial and my file references are correct. Ive even tried adding the javascript modal.show thing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-                 labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;     </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    ...
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
   </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

</body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the `js/bootstrap.min.js` file after the jquery files.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap.min.js` requires jQuery to work properly.

Here, I tidied up your code and fixed the error (probably):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">...</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
    </body>

</html>
```